# Web console (GUI) for apache ignite

Tags: gui, user-interface, apache

We need a basic web console on apache ignite just to check cluster health and basic checks, is there any OpenSource tool available?
We have checked few tools:

- [Ignite Web Console](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/Web+Console) - Looks like its very old and not supported with current versions.
- [GridGain Control Center](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/tools/gg-control-center) - No proper documentation and also not sure which tool to install and some of them are not free to use.